# What does the number mean that is followed by + sign after the error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Considering the below two line

System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable) +115

datautility.table(String q) in \ghty\domains\j-1055490192\user\htdocs\App_Code\datautility.cs:31

the :31 in last line mean the line number, but what does +115 signify? I am not able to get anything on google, may be I dont know how to query google for this. Please tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here: http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2005/01/25/funny-numbers-in-my-stack-trace.aspx

That number is a (native) instruction offset from the method start.